CTkSlider и его обновление
Есть проблемка, когда я нажимаю кнопку "Дальше", то песня меняется, но и скорость слайдера + показ времени меняется сильно(например, на 3 песне уже будет показывать 0:1, 0:3, 0:5). Честно, не могу понять почему он начинает значительно ускоряться, хотя я вроде все сбрасываю в 0.
from tkinter import *
from customtkinter import *
from pygame import mixer
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilenames
from PIL import Image
import pywinstyles
mixer.init()


# "Двигатель" слайдера
def move_slider(value):
    position = int(value)
    # Установка позиции воспроизведения
    if mixer.music.get_busy():
        mixer.music.set_pos(position)


# Основной класс
class MusicPlayer:
    def __init__(self, window):

        # Задаем переменные
        self.music_file = None
        self.playing_state = False
        self.queuemus = []
        self.queue_musicfortext = []

        # Создаем окно
        window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        window.resizable(0, 0)
        window.title('Music')
        self.screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

        # Шрифт
        self.Font_tuple = ("Comic Sans MS", 20, "bold")

        # Изображения
        self.image_pause_hover = CTkImage(light_image=Image.open('image/pause.png'), size=(50, 50))
        self.image_play_hover = CTkImage(light_image=Image.open('image/play.png'), size=(50, 50))
        self.image_stop_hover = CTkImage(light_image=Image.open('image/stop.png'), size=(50, 50))

        # Детали дизайна
        self.Play = CTkButton(window, text="", image=self.image_play_hover, command=self.playing, width=50,
                              fg_color='transparent', hover=False)
        self.Pause = CTkButton(window, text="", image=self.image_pause_hover, command=self.pause, width=50,
                               fg_color='transparent', hover=False)
        self.Stop = CTkButton(window, text="", image=self.image_stop_hover, command=self.stop, width=50,
                              fg_color='transparent', hover=False)
        self.Slider = CTkSlider(window, from_=0, to=100, command=move_slider, width=int(self.screen_width * 0.8))
        self.Slider.set(0)
        self.label_startsong = CTkLabel(window, text="-:-", font=self.Font_tuple)
        self.label_finalsong = CTkLabel(window, text="-:-", font=self.Font_tuple)
        self.label_name = CTkLabel(window, text="", font=self.Font_tuple)
        self.Selecter = CTkButton(window, text="Выбрать", command=self.load_onefile, width=50, font=self.Font_tuple,
                                  hover=False)
        self.label_queue = CTkLabel(window, text="Очередь:", font=self.Font_tuple)
        self.queue_text = CTkTextbox(window, width=int(self.screen_width * 0.2), height=int(self.screen_height * 0.95),
                                     font=self.Font_tuple)
        self.right_button = CTkButton(window, text="Дальше", width=50, command=self.right)
        self.left_button = CTkButton(window, text="Назад", width=50)
        # Внешний вид кнопок
        pywinstyles.set_opacity(self.Play, value=0.5, color="#000001")
        pywinstyles.set_opacity(self.Stop, value=0.5, color="#000001")
        pywinstyles.set_opacity(self.Pause, value=0.5, color="#000001")

        # Расположение
        self.Selecter.place(x=self.screen_width * 0.0095, y=1)  # Кнопка выбора
        self.Play.place(x=self.screen_width * 0.8 // 2, y=self.screen_height * 0.92)   # Кнопка Play
        self.Pause.place(x=self.screen_width * 0.8 // 2 - (self.screen_width * 0.04),
                         y=self.screen_height * 0.92)  # Кнопка Pause
        self.Stop.place(x=self.screen_width * 0.8 // 2 + (self.screen_width * 0.04),
                        y=self.screen_height * 0.92)  # Кнопка Stop
        self.Slider.place(x=self.screen_width * 0.0095, y=self.screen_height * 0.9)  # Ползунок
        self.label_startsong.place(x=self.screen_width * 0.0095, y=self.screen_height * 0.92)  # Начало песни
        self.label_finalsong.place(x=self.screen_width * 0.8 - self.screen_width * 0.011,
                                   y=self.screen_height * 0.92)  # Конец песни
        self.label_name.place(x=self.screen_width * 0.0095, y=self.screen_height * 0.85)  # Название песни
        self.label_queue.place(x=self.screen_width * 0.8, y=self.screen_height * 0.01)
        self.queue_text.place(x=self.screen_width * 0.8, y=self.screen_height * 0.05)
        self.right_button.place(x=self.screen_width * 0.8 // 2 + (self.screen_width * 0.08),
                                y=self.screen_height * 0.92)
        self.left_button.place(x=self.screen_width * 0.8 // 2 - (self.screen_width * 0.08), y=self.screen_height * 0.92)

    # Загрузка 1 файла
    def load_onefile(self):
        try:
            # Получаем список выбранных файлов
            file_paths = askopenfilenames(filetypes=[('Audio Files', '*.wav *.ogg *.mp3')])
            # Проверяем, что файлы были выбраны
            if file_paths:
                for file_path in file_paths:
                    self.queuemus.append(file_path)  # Добавляем файл в очередь музыки
                    self.music_names(file_path)  # Добавляем название трека в текстовый интерфейс
                # Если музыка не воспроизводится:
                if not mixer.music.get_busy():
                    self.play()  # Воспроизводим первый трек
                    del self.queuemus[0]  # И удаляем его
                    del self.queue_musicfortext[0]  # И название тоже удаляем
                self.update_queue_display()  # Обновляем боковую панель
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Не удалось загрузить файл: {e}')

    def update_queue_display(self, queue_text=None):
        self.queue_text.delete(1.0, END)  # Очищаем текущее содержимое текстового поля
        if queue_text is not None:
            self.queue_text.insert(END, self.queue_text)  # Если передан текст, вставляем его
        else:
            for song in self.queue_musicfortext:
                self.queue_text.insert(END, song + '\n')  # Добавляем каждое название трека в текстовое поле

    # Получение названия трека
    def music_names(self, file):
        try:
            # Получаем название последней песни из очереди
            music_name = file.split('/')[-1].split('.')[:-1]  # Название песни
            if len(music_name) > 1:
                song_title = music_name[1]
            else:
                song_title = music_name[0]
            # Добавляем название песни в очередь для отображения
            self.queue_musicfortext.append(song_title.strip())
            # Обновляем текстовое поле с названиями песен
            self.queue_text.insert("end", f"{song_title.strip()}\n")

        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Не удалось загрузить файл: {e}')

    # Начать играть песню
    def play(self):
        try:
            self.music_file = self.queuemus[0]
            if self.music_file:
                music_length = mixer.Sound(self.queuemus[0]).get_length()  # Получаем длину музыки
                self.label_startsong.configure(text="0:0")
                self.label_finalsong.configure(text=f"{int(music_length // 60)}:{int(music_length % 60)}")
                self.label_name.configure(text=self.queue_musicfortext[0])
                self.queue_text.delete(1.0, "end")
                self.queue_text.insert(1.0, f"Сейчас играет: {self.queue_musicfortext[0]}\n")
                mixer.music.load(self.music_file)  # Загрузка музыки при загрузке файла
                self.Slider.configure(to=mixer.Sound(self.music_file).get_length())  # Установка длины слайдера
                self.Slider.set(0)  # Сброс слайдера
                mixer.music.play()
                self.playing_state = True
                mixer.music.set_pos(self.Slider.get())
            # Начать обновление слайдера
            self.update_slider()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Ошибка: {e}")  # Ошибка

    # Начать играть после паузы или после стопа
    def playing(self):
        try:
            if not self.playing_state:
                self.playing_state = True
                mixer.music.unpause()
                current_position = self.Slider.get()
                mixer.music.set_pos(current_position)
                self.update_slider()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Ошибка: {e}")  # Ошибка

    # Пауза
    def pause(self):
        try:
            if self.playing_state:
                self.playing_state = False
                mixer.music.pause()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Ошибка: {e}")  # Ошибка

    # Стоп
    def stop(self):
        try:
            self.Slider.set(0)  # Сброс ползунка
            current_position = self.Slider.get()
            mixer.music.set_pos(current_position) # Сбрасываем песню в 0
            self.label_startsong.configure(text="0:0")
            self.pause()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Ошибка: {e}")  # Ошибка

    # Обновляем/двигаем слайдер
    def update_slider(self):
        try:
            if mixer.music.get_busy() and self.music_file:
                # Обновление слайдера каждые полсекунды
                current_position = self.Slider.get() + 0.5
                self.Slider.set(current_position)
                minutes = int(current_position // 60)
                seconds = int(current_position % 60)
                self.label_startsong.configure(text=f"{minutes}:{seconds}")
                self.Slider.after(500, self.update_slider)
            if not mixer.music.get_busy() and self.playing_state:
                self.play()
                del self.queuemus[0]
                del self.queue_musicfortext[0]
                self.update_queue_display()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Ошибка: {e}")  # Ошибка

    # Двигать дальше
    def right(self):
        try:
            self.play()
            del self.queuemus[0]
            del self.queue_musicfortext[0]
            self.update_queue_display()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Ошибка: {e}")  # Ошибка


# Отрисовка окна
root = CTk()
set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")
set_appearance_mode("dark")
app = MusicPlayer(root)
root.mainloop()

